# CSS, background color/image

Tags: css, background, fill

I want to add some background colour to block h1 tag but I don't want to see background behind the text. Is it possible?

For example background with (-), It will seen like this:

Welcome -----------------

after text like filling with (-)

Thanks for help

Comment: Your question is not very clear.Sorry.Can you explain it properly?

Comment: Post your code or try to explain it more clearly so that everyone understand better

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `h1` tag as as `inline-block`, and keep it within a `div`. Assign th required the background color to the `div` while assigning a background of white to the `h1`. You will get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
h1 {
    width: 200px;
    background-image: url(line.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left bottom;
}

h1 span {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
</style>


<h1><span>Welcome</span></h1>
```

see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/WtPB5/2/